Spring boot Spring data jpa - app for data persistence to remote Mariadb server
I am trying to run Spring boot app with the aim to persist and retrieve data from remote Mariadb server, but cannot find the reason for failing. As this is kind of training/test project, before the real one, I first tried with localhost H2 database and everything was running. The next attemp was with this remote Mariadb, running on Raspberry Pi 3B, and the app is on windows machine in the same LAN. Using Postman(tried with web browser too), after trying GET or POST to http://localhost:8080/home/owner I got the following error/trace:
"timestamp": "2024-11-12T20:48:29.086+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "trace": "org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource home/owner.\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:585)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:52)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)\r\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)\r\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:384)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:905)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)\r\n",
    "message": "No static resource home/owner.",
    "path": "/home/owner"

The strange thing is that there isn't anything on the IntelliJ IDEA log, as if the request doesn't reach it at all. To me this looks like the RestController doesn't work/there is something wrong with the mapping/, or some kind of issue between the services(using Postman and IntelliJ) but the same code with the only difference that I used local H2, was working as expected. So I decided to check what is happening on the MariaDB side and systemctl status mariadb.service returned "Aborted connection xx to db: 'xyz' user: 'remote_admin' host: '10.10.10.101' (Got an error reading communication packets)"
Here I have to say, that I created a DB, user, granted permissions and prepared the server for the connection, by setting the bind-address = 0.0.0.0 in /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf to be able to access it from remote machine and also setting max_allowed_packet = 256M in /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf as per advice from another similar issue. I am not sure where the response posted a few rows above comes from -if it is from the RestController or from the remote db server, through the controller. Below is the source of the Entity, the RestController, the POM.xml and application.properties.
Entity:

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "owner")
public class Owner {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "personal_id")
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String email;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "car")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Car car;

    public Owner(Integer id, String name, String surname, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name
                + " "
                + this.surname;
    }
}

RestController:
package controller;

import Service.OwnerService;
import dto.OwnerDto;
import dto.OwnerResponseDto;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class OwnerController {

    private OwnerService ownerService;

    @Autowired
    public OwnerController(OwnerService ownerService) {
        this.ownerService = ownerService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/owner")
    public ResponseEntity<List<OwnerResponseDto>> getAllOwners() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ownerService.getAllOwners(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/owner/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<OwnerResponseDto> getOwnerById(@PathVariable int id) {
        OwnerResponseDto requestedOwner = ownerService.getOwnerById(id);
        if (requestedOwner == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(requestedOwner, HttpStatus.FOUND);
    }

    @PostMapping("/owner")
    public ResponseEntity<OwnerResponseDto> addOwner(@RequestBody OwnerDto dto) {
        OwnerResponseDto addedOwner = ownerService.addOwner(dto);
        if (addedOwner == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(addedOwner, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PutMapping("/owner/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<OwnerResponseDto> updateOwner(@RequestBody OwnerDto dto, @PathVariable int id) {
        OwnerResponseDto updatedOwner = ownerService.updateOwner(dto, id);
        if (updatedOwner == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(updatedOwner, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/owner/{id}")
    public void deleteOwner(int id) {
        ownerService.deleteOwner(id);
    }
}

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.training</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>car-park</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

application.properties:
spring.application.name=car-park

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://10.10.10.102:3306/springboot
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=remote_admin
spring.datasource.password=user1admin1

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl.auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect

Really thank You to those, who lost some time to read this long post. Every advice is higly appreciated. Apology if it isn't clear and concise enough, but that's my maximum after a long exhausting day of useless reading and troubleshooting.

The fact that your package for the controller is controller makes me wonder what package your @SpringBootApplication is in. Feels like you aren't following the suggested practices for structuring your Spring Boot application.

The @SpringBootApplication is in the main package(straight into the source folder/one level up in hierarchy), named by the spring initializr. Regarding the other packagaes - they are, service , repository, model, dto. I am a self learner and stick to the practices that I find, when I read and watch video guides. So, that's what I have seen them using in their guides. Maybe this doesn't stick to the recommended practices, I will check, thank you for this note.

Don't put stuff in the top-level (or rather no-package) that is a bad practice all together. At least put it in something like com.example (and the other packages as well).
